# Expand a variable inside `` command

Tags: bash

I could not find the exact reference to what I'm doing...

I have the following script that does not expand the variable inside the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="my name"
`convert -pointsize 250 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf -fill black -draw 'text 330,900 "$name"' tag.jpg name_my.jpg`
```

This results in an image that has the text $name instead of the content of name.

I actually need to read lines from a file and rund the command on each name so my real script is(has the same problem):

```
arr=(`cat names.txt`)
for (( i=0; i<${len}; i+=2 ));
do
        `convert -pointsize 250 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf -fill black -draw 'text 330,900 "$(${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]})"' tag.jpg name_${arr[i]}.jpg`
done
```

Comment: You don't need backticks at all to run `convert` in your example.

Comment: Does it show how long it's been since I touched this? :) 
This is how I was taught to write Bash in the uni... I read somewhere that it supports `Bourne Shell`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an escaping problem.
either use proper escaping with backslash, or make sure otherewise that the $args are not "protected" by single quotes.
e.g.

```
name="bla"
# using escape character \
value1="foo \"${name}\""
# putting single-quotes inside double-quotes
value2="foo '"${name}"'"
```

to better see what is going on, try to break down the problem into multiple smaller problems.
e.g. create the "draw" command with all expansions before using it in convert

```
name="my name"
draw="text 330, 900 '"${name}"'"
convert -pointsize 250 -fill black -draw "${draw}" tag.jpg name_my.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is single quotes (`''`) not backticks. Because `$name` is within them, it won't be expanded. Instead, you should use double quotes and you can escape the inner quotes like this:

```
`convert -pointsize 250 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf -fill black -draw "text 330,900 \"$name\"" tag.jpg name_my.jpg`
```

Comment: I know my question is a fundamental, but for some reason just taking your solution only produced '\' as the text